# Icons as bullet points in reveal.js Quarto

Tags: r, icons, quarto, reveal.js

I would like to use icons as bullet points in a `reveal.js` presentation. I would like to use this [icon](https://icons.getbootstrap.com/icons/robot/) where we can copy the HTML SVG lines in the presentation. Now I would like to replace the `-` bullet points with an icon because when adding text after the icon doesn't work like a bullet point. Here is some reproducible code:

```
---
title: "Example"
format: revealjs
---

# Example slide

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="50" height="50" fill="currentColor" class="bi bi-robot" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
  <path d="M6 12.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5M3 8.062C3 6.76 4.235 5.765 5.53 5.886a26.6 26.6 0 0 0 4.94 0C11.765 5.765 13 6.76 13 8.062v1.157a.93.93 0 0 1-.765.935c-.845.147-2.34.346-4.235.346s-3.39-.2-4.235-.346A.93.93 0 0 1 3 9.219zm4.542-.827a.25.25 0 0 0-.217.068l-.92.9a25 25 0 0 1-1.871-.183.25.25 0 0 0-.068.495c.55.076 1.232.149 2.02.193a.25.25 0 0 0 .189-.071l.754-.736.847 1.71a.25.25 0 0 0 .404.062l.932-.97a25 25 0 0 0 1.922-.188.25.25 0 0 0-.068-.495c-.538.074-1.207.145-1.98.189a.25.25 0 0 0-.166.076l-.754.785-.842-1.7a.25.25 0 0 0-.182-.135"/>
  <path d="M8.5 1.866a1 1 0 1 0-1 0V3h-2A4.5 4.5 0 0 0 1 7.5V8a1 1 0 0 0-1 1v2a1 1 0 0 0 1 1v1a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h10a2 2 0 0 0 2-2v-1a1 1 0 0 0 1-1V9a1 1 0 0 0-1-1v-.5A4.5 4.5 0 0 0 10.5 3h-2zM14 7.5V13a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H3a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V7.5A3.5 3.5 0 0 1 5.5 4h5A3.5 3.5 0 0 1 14 7.5"/>
</svg> This is some text
```

Output:

[image]

As you can see the text is shown below the icon while I want it after the icon like bullet point structure. So I was wondering if anyone knows how to replace bullet points with icons in reveal.js `Quarto`.

Comment: I think CSS might help you here, although I didn't try it. Set up a <span> element or assign a class to your <li>.